# CSS Styling headers and following content

Tags: css, header, styling

The following very basic problem styling content with headers. I have the following situation:
usually the content is structured the following way:

```
<h1>Main Header</h1>
<h2>Sub Header</h2>
<p>Content</p>
```

But in some cases the Sub Header isn't present. I would like to add a different padding/margin between the main header and content, when the content follows directly without the sub header.

I feel like there must be a simple solution to this that I'm overseeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html):

```
h1 + p {
    /* ... */
}
```

This just selects the `<p/>` if it is directly after the `<h1/>`.

Comment: well there you have it! i didn't realize that selector existed! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lose margin-bottoms and use margin-tops instead.

This way `margin-top: 15px` on `<p>` will give space of 15px no matter whats above it.

Comment: you are right. but i don't want to have that much space if h1 and h2 are present. so the above h1 + p sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 + p {
  margin-top: ...;
}
```

That will only select p preceded by h1

Answer (score -2):

You can try `overflow:hidden` property for this.